# CPU load of iptables to deny IPs during DDoS event

Tags: firewalls, ddos, iptables

If a server has an external IP address protected with an iptables whitelist rule to reject all by default except from 3 ip addresses ip1, ip2 and ip3.

If someone identifies this external IP address, although it won't be responding to anything because of iptables, and starts DDoSing it with 10, 20 or 30 GBPS of data, will the amount of processing be negligible on the server receiving this traffic or not ?

Are there any public measurements done on how much CPU processing it takes on the host machine when dropping a packet with iptables to be able to do simple back of the envelope calculations based on estimated bandwidth of DDoS attack.

Comment: It depends on the packet size though, you shouldn't measure it in a magnitude of GBps, but rather packets per second.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to pose this question on netfilter mailing list. http://www.netfilter.org/mailinglists.html. You would likely get a more comprehensive reply there since the question is very specific.

Comment: Ok will do this in parallel. Would be interesting if anyone here has had some exposure to that before.

Comment: It will depend on what hardware you are using, and on how you structure your iptables rules.